# Should I care about these benchmark values?

Tags: truffle, test, benchmark

Let's say I have a contract which, for the sake of this post, inherits OpenZeppelin's `Ownable`. I made a minor update (in terms of code / complexity: an override & revert to disable a method). Then I added tests, and the results were like this:

```
Contract: SampleMetaverse
  ✓ does not allow renouncing the ownership (using: account 0)
  ✓ does not allow transferring ownership to others than the owner (using: account 1)
  ✓ allows transferring ownership to self (using: account 0) (407ms)
  ✓ allows transferring ownership to others (using: account 0) (89ms)
  ✓ does not allow renouncing the ownership (using: account 1)
  ✓ allows transferring ownership to self (using: account 1) (115ms)
  ✓ allows transferring ownership to others (using: account 1) (92ms)
```

I see the numbers in milliseconds to be *in red* (this is a truffle test). To what extent should I care about this?

The contract (the part I am testing) goes like this, actually:

```
abstract contract SafeOwnable is Ownable {
    constructor() Ownable() {}

    /**
     * @dev Trying to renounce the ownership is forbidden in these contracts.
     */
    function renounceOwnership() public override onlyOwner {
        revert("SafeOwnable: ownership cannot be renounced");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a concern.

The redness is an artifact of the test framework that happens to think the times are a little on the high side. This is irrelevant.

Transactions that arrive in blocks can be considered as executed in the past. All nodes are therefore in catch-up mode. Any reasonably fast computer can process everything in a block before the next block arrives. The maximum complexity of a block is limited by the block gas limit.

You should be concerned with the maximum gas consumption of a transaction, and time complexity (aim for *O(1)*), but temporal time is of no concern at all.

Hope it helps.